# Can C/C++ optimizers decide to lazily evaluate values that are only used in a short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-optimization, short-circuiting

I like to refactor complicated conditionals like this:

```
if (foo(blah) || (bar(param1, param2, param3) && !obj.longMethodName())) ...
```

into this:

```
bool foo_true = foo(blah);
bool bar_true = bar(param1, param2, param3);
bool long_true = obj.longMethodName();

if (foo_true || (bar_true && !long_true)) ...
```

I think this makes the code a lot easier to understand, and it helps with debugging because you can see the intermediate results used to compute the final condition.

But: in the original code, due to short circuiting, `bar` will only be evaluated if `foo` returns `true`, and `longMethodName` only if `bar` returns `true`.

Assume that functions are "pure", methods are `const`, and the compiler can see the function bodies of everything.  **Are C++ optimizers allowed to defer evaluating my intermediate values until they are needed?**

Comment: Do you expect the compiler to look for side effects? And with the way you call them in your second example (and they have side effects), did you *want* the side effects even though the return value may not be needed?

Comment: One at least hope that you make your `bool`s `const`, if the aim was to improve clarity. :)

Comment: oh yeah, that should have been obvious.  Assume that all functions are "pure" and methods are `const`.  But you're right, I doubt compilers would be able to prove that in most cases.

Comment: Why don't use macro? C/C++ don't have [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

Comment: C++ compilers are allowed to do Out of order execution and memory reordering as far as it doesn't have side effects on the program, but this is different from lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

Of course.  Provided the compiler can see enough to determine
that `foo`, `bar` and `obj.longMethodName()` don't have any
other impact on the observable behavior of your code.

Whether any compilers do is another question.  I rather doubt
it; it would require some very special logic, which isn't in the
usual list of optimization techniques, for something that
practically nobody does.  (I suspect that most programmers would
find the original version, formatted correctly, to be more
readable than the one with a lot of extra variables.)

### EDIT:

I wonder if it's worth pointing out that the compiler is allowed
to call all three functions even if the if is written:

```
if ( foo( blah ) || (bar( p1, p2, p3 ) && ! obj.lMN() ) )
```

(Although I can't imagine one that would.)  The standard makes
no requirements with regards to which functions are called when;
it only requires that the observable behavior be the same (same
values and in the same order---no guarantees with regards to
time) "as if" the formal semantics of the program were followed.
And the only things that count as observable behavior is IO
(in some form) and accesses to volatile objects.

Comment: Wrong answer. In the example above what happens if `foo(blah)` returns false ? In the first case `bar`won't be called but in the second case it will be called, and as `bar`can have side effects the two programs are no longer equivalant.

Comment: Assume that `bar` has no side effects and the compiler knows the full source code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: if `bar` has side effects then "provided the compiler can see enough to determine that ..." does not hold. The compiler cannot determine something that isn't true. So the answer is correct.

Comment: "it would require some very special logic" -- would it though, or would it just require everything to be inlined and then re-ordered? I'm not saying this is trivial ofc, just that it's within the realm of things compilers already have mechanisms for and so might not necessarily require special treatment.

Comment: @SteveJessop: have a look at doron's answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I've seen it. This answer does not contradict it. Since that answer the questioner has clarified that he's prepared to assume the case where all function bodies are visible to the compiler, so what doron describes as "the problem" doesn't apply.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Obviously, the optimization only applies if the functions not being called don't affect the observable behavior.  I  stated this in my answer.  But that's something the compiler could (usually, at least) determine.  Most won't bother to do the analysis in this case, but they are certainly allowed to do it.

Comment: @SteveJessop It would require some special logic, beyond what is usually done in optimizers.  This is almost the opposite of loop invariant motion (hoisting code which always gives the same results out of the loop).  I don't think the necessary logic is any more complex than that required for a lot of other optimizations, but I've never heard of it being considered.  (On the other hand, it's been some twenty years since I worked on compilers, so things may have changed.  Still, most compilers I see today don't do half of what we knew how to do 20 years ago.)

Comment: @James: seems strange to me. Suppose that the line `bool bar_true = bar(param1, param2, param3);` were replaced with `bool bar_true = param1 && param2;`. Would it still be beyond the wit of compilers to change where that is executed, given necessary assumptions about DFA proving that `param1` and `param2` are not modified between the point the statement occurs and the point the result is used?

Comment: @SteveJessop I think I may have misstated the case.  It's not any more complicated that loop invariant motion; it might even be less.  It's just that as far as I know, it's not among the various code movement considerations that I've heard about.  Typically, the code movement used to e.g. avoid pipeline stalls and such takes place after the decision to call a function or not, and doesn't look into function calls.

Comment: @JamesKanze: OK, and I'm being very hand-wavy. It's not that I think compilers should explicitly move the function call around, it's that my mental model is that after inlining, code becomes a complete soup of operations almost independent of the original statements that defined them, and I expect to find the actual evaluation almost anywhere when I look at the asm ;-) So given that I would expect different parts of the `bar` function call to end up all over the place, I can't quite believe that they won't make it to the place the result is used.

Comment: @SteveJessop Maybe it is today:-).  I'm describing what was considered state of the art 20 years ago.

Comment: +1 I am sure this is the correct answer, I am wondering there are any references besides the `as-if` rule? I am guessing there isn't but it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The as-if rule pretty much covers everything a compiler can and cannot do with regards to optimization.  Although we generally speak of the as-if rule, what 1.9 really does is specify what an implementation must do at the least.  Beyond that, the implementation has total liberty.

Answer (score 1):

No. You compiler is not allowed to make the optimisation because it can not determine wether you have meant the short circuit or wether you want to have a potential side effect of evaluating `bar` no matter what.

Comment: This is wrong.  The compiler is definitely allowed to do the optimization, under the as if rule.  (It might have difficulty proving that the optimization does result in the same observable behavior, but the standard certainly allows the optimization.)

Answer (score 0):

No.  C++ has no concept of a pure method with no side effects, so there really isn't a way to optimize that.

Comment: C++ doesn't (formally) need such.  The compiler is allowed to do anything (absolutely anything), provided the observable behavior of the program are respected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `foo` and `bar` could be implemented in another compilation unit and C++ does not have the concept of function purity. This means that `foo` and `bar` might have side effects (changes to screen or global variables) and therefore must be evaluated in order for you to get expected behaviour.

Interestingly enough, with GCC, functions can be declared with the `pure` attribute. This tells the compiler that the function does not have any side effects. And therefore can be called lazily. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) for more details.

Comment: Suppose they are all being compiled together with full program optimization enabled.  No DLLs or static libs.  Best case scenario.

Comment: By compiled together I mean in the same compilation unit (source file) since only the linker gets to see other compilation units. In such a case, the optimizer is entitled to optimize the function out since we it would be 'as if' the function was called. In practice, doubt any optimizers would actually go this far.

Comment: @doron "only the linker gets to see other compilation units".  Of course.  But in all modern compilers, when full optimization is turned on, it is the linker which generates the actual code.  Cross module optimization cannot really be considered an exotic technique today, given that even VC++ and g++ support it.

Comment: Yes, gcc supports the -lto (link time optimization) flag but it certainly is not on by default, it will cause problems with debug information and is not on by default for any standard optimization (-Ox) flag. Clang probably has better support due to use of llvm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the assignment would be counted as a side-effect already. To say the least it is probably hard to determine if it is safe to move the actual call.

But, I would like to point out that in c++11 it is possible to achieve what OP pursues with nearly exact same syntax that OP uses in examples utilizing [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

It is just that `foo_true`, would not be defined as

`bool foo_true = foo(blah);`

but rather

`auto foo_true = std::bind(foo, blah)`.

The `if` could be then checked as `if(  foo_true() || bar_true() )`.

Whether it is cleaner or not, is up to personal matter IMO. But I believe it behaves as both wanted, and expected. Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

bool foo(int blah){
    cout << "blah: " << blah << '\n';
    return blah;
}

bool bar(bool negate_me){
    cout << "negate_me: " << negate_me << '\n';
    return !negate_me;
}

int main() {
    bool test = true;
    int param = 42;
    auto foo_true = std::bind(foo, test);
    auto bar_true = std::bind(bar, param);

    if (foo_true() || bar_true() ) cout << "TEST\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
blah: 1
TEST
```

`bar` wasn't called. Change `test` to `false` and it will be.

Comment: The standard is quite clear what are "side effects" in this regard: IO and reads and writes of volatile objects.  If he declared the variables `volatile`, then the optimization wouldn't be valid.

Comment: On the other hand, the idea of using `std::bind` or lambda functions is original; it's a way of guaranteeing that the functions won't be called unless necessary.

Comment: Sadly, I have just tested this out and the compiler is unable to inline my lambda functions.

Comment: @JamesKanze That was my point. I know the answer could be called off topic. I just thought, that it is possible to move the actual call and thought it is worth of sharing, I thought of lambda too, but think it would bloat/pollute code a bit more. I am not very literate when it comes to standard. I imagine implementing special logic, for `static`/global variables, shared memory areas and stuff could be complicated, for compiler creators. I completely share your stance, that if the behaviour does not change compiler is free-to-go.

Comment: @japreiss You don't have to use lambda if you use `bind`, I also don't think the lambda has to be inlined. The thing is, when it gets called.

Comment: @luk32 No function has to be inlined, and for the most part, none will unless you request at least a little bit of optimization.